# Applying Jquery to a Smarty variable

Tags: jquery, smarty

I'm trying to make a vote system using jQuery and Smarty. Here is vote variable in Smarty :

```
<p><span id="votenum">{$q_vote}</span>
```

I want to increase the vote by 1 if the question is successfully upvoted, this is what I wrote for the jQuery part to increase the vote :

```
$("votenum").html($("#votenum").html(parseInt($("#votenum"))+1));
```

But it doesn't work. Can you tell me how can I fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $("#votenum").text(function(i, txt) {
        return parseInt(txt, 10) + 1;
    });
});
```

An ID is selected with the `#` sign, and using an anonymous function makes it trivial to add 1 to the value, and you don't have to look up the element twice, just make sure you're using a radix with the parseInt function.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#votenum").text( parseInt($("#votenum").text()) + 1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the problem using...

```
$("votenum").html($("#votenum").html(parseInt($("#votenum").text())+1));
```

But a better way would be..

```
var votenum = $("#votenum");
var num = parseInt(votenum.text());
votenum.html(num+1);
```

This is more efficient as it only selects votenum once.